# Implementing Spring Environment Interface for testing

Tags: java, spring, scala, unit-testing

I'm wanting to implement the Spring `Environment` interface in order to test my class, but I can't find the interface implementation anywhere and don't know what values they should return, or where to get them.

I'm writing tests using Scala Tests and have run into the issue of having to implement the `Environment` interface that's passed around in Spring. However, I am getting an error saying that the values I'm returning for the implemented methods, aren't valid

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Invalid name: conductor.ldap.baseDn; nested exception is javax.naming.InvalidNameException: Invalid name: conductor.ldap.baseDn 
org.springframework.ldap.InvalidNameException: Invalid name: conductor.ldap.baseDn; nested exception is javax.naming.InvalidNameException: Invalid name: conductor.ldap.baseDn
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:136)
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.newLdapName(LdapUtils.java:416)
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapNameBuilder.add(LdapNameBuilder.java:121)
    at com.ojolabs.conductor.engine.services.GluuIdmIdentityService.<init>(GluuIdmIdentityService.scala:28)
    at GluuIdmIdentityServiceTest.<init>(GluuIdmIdentityServiceTest.scala:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
```

I know this is happening because I'm returning incorrect values, but I haven't been able to find documentation showing what value is expected to be returned.

Here is the class I'm trying to test

```
@Component
class GluuIdmIdentityService @Autowired() (ldapTemplate: LdapTemplate, env: Environment) extends IdmIdentityServiceImpl with StrictLogging {

  private val baseDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance().add(env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.ldap.baseDn")).build()
  private val userBaseDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(baseDn).add(env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.ldap.userBaseDn")).build()
  private val groupBaseDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(baseDn).add(env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.ldap.groupBaseDn")).build()

  private val userByIdCache: LoadingCache[String, Option[LdapUser]] = {
    CacheBuilder.
      newBuilder().
      maximumSize(500).
      expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).
      build(new CacheLoader[String, Option[LdapUser]] {
        override def load(key: String): Option[LdapUser] = getUser(key)
      })

  }

  private def getUser(id: String): Option[LdapUser] = {
    val query = LdapQueryBuilder.query().base(userBaseDn).where("uid").is(id)

    val users = try {
      ldapTemplate.search(query, new AbstractContextMapper[LdapUser] {
        override def doMapFromContext(ctx: DirContextOperations): LdapUser = {

          val fullUserDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(userBaseDn).add("inum", ctx.getStringAttribute("inum")).build()
          val groupQuery = LdapQueryBuilder.query().base(groupBaseDn).where("member").is(fullUserDn.toString)

          val groups: Seq[LdapGroup] = try {
            ldapTemplate.search(groupQuery, new AbstractContextMapper[LdapGroup] {
              override def doMapFromContext(groupCtx: DirContextOperations): LdapGroup = {

                LdapGroup(
                  LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(ctx.getDn).build(),
                  Option(groupCtx.getStringAttribute("displayName")).getOrElse(""),
                  Option(groupCtx.getStringAttribute("description")).getOrElse(""),
                  Option(groupCtx.getStringAttribute("gluuGroupType"))
                )
              }
            }).asScala

          } catch {
            case e: NamingException =>
              throw new FlowableException(s"Could not find groups for user $id", e)
          }

          LdapUser(
            LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(ctx.getDn).build(),
            ctx.getStringAttribute("uid"),
            Option(ctx.getStringAttribute("givenName")),
            Option(ctx.getStringAttribute("sn")),
            Option(ctx.getStringAttribute("mail")),
            Option(ctx.getStringAttribute("displayName")),
            groups
          )
        }
      }).asScala
    } catch {
      case e: NamingException =>
        throw new FlowableException(s"Could not find user with id $id", e)
    }

    if(users.size > 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"More than one user returned for UID $id")
    } else {
      users.headOption
    }
  }

  override def createUserQuery(): UserQuery = new CachedUserQuery(userByIdCache)

  override def createGroupQuery(): GroupQuery = new CachedGroupQuery(userByIdCache)

  override def checkPassword(userId: String, password: String): Boolean = {
    //TODO: Ldap actually does support auth, build this in at some point
    throw new FlowableException("Gluu identity provider does not currently support authentication.")
  }

  override def newUser(userId: String): User ={
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support creating a new user")
  }

  override def saveUser(user: User): Unit = {
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support saving an user")
  }

  override def createNativeUserQuery(): NativeUserQuery = {
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support native querying")
  }

  override def deleteUser(userId: String): Unit = {
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support deleting an user")
  }

  override def newGroup(groupId: String): Group = {
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support creating a new group")
  }

  override def createNativeGroupQuery(): NativeGroupQuery = {
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support native querying")
  }

  override def saveGroup(group: Group): Unit = {
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support saving a group")
  }

  override def deleteGroup(groupId: String): Unit = {
    throw new FlowableException("LDAP identity service doesn't support deleting a group")
  }
```

Here is my test

```
class GluuIdmIdentityServiceTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {


  val env: Environment = new Environment {
    override def getDefaultProfiles = Array("default")
    override def getActiveProfiles = Array("default")

    override def acceptsProfiles(profiles: String*): Boolean = true

    override def getRequiredProperty(key: String): String = key

    override def getRequiredProperty[T](key: String, targetType: Class[T]) = targetType.cast(AnyRef)

    override def getProperty(key: String) = key

    override def getProperty(key: String, defaultValue: String) = key

    override def getProperty[T](key: String, targetType: Class[T]) = targetType.cast(AnyRef)

    override def getProperty[T](key: String, targetType: Class[T], defaultValue: T) = targetType.cast(AnyRef)

    override def resolveRequiredPlaceholders(text: String): String = text

    override def resolvePlaceholders(text: String): String = text

    override def containsProperty(key: String) = true
  }

  val source = new LdapContextSource()

  source.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.ldap.serverUrl"))
  source.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.ldap.bindDn"))
  source.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.ldap.bindPassword"))
  //source.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("conductor.ldap.baseDn"))
  source.setPooled(true)

  val ldapTemplate: LdapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(source)

  val idm: GluuIdmIdentityService = new GluuIdmIdentityService(ldapTemplate, env)

  "Create Group Query" should "return group query" in {

    assert(idm.createGroupQuery().isInstanceOf[GroupQuery])

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`StandardEnvironment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html) class instead of re-implementing the interface.